# php date 1 month earlier

Tags: php, date

well im using this function to get the summer time in mexico.

```
function horarioVerano() { 
$year  = date("Y"); 
$ahora = strtotime(date("d-m-Y"));   

$inicio_invierno = strtotime("last Sunday April $year");
//echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $inicio_invierno); 

$fin_invierno = strtotime("last Sunday November $year"); 
//echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $fin_invierno); 

if ($ahora > $inicio_invierno && $ahora <= $fin_invierno) 
   $num = 5; 
else 
   $num = 6;

return $num;
```

}

but i always get the previous month date, if i `echo date("Y-m-d",$inicio_invierno)` i get 2011-03-27 and not 2011-04-24 as it should be , same for any other month i walways get the previous month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"last Sunday April $year" is parsed as "April $year" (which gives the first of the month) and then calculating "last Sunday" relative to that. If you want the last Sunday of April, say just that: "last Sunday **of** April $year". See [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) for details.

Comment: Remember that the format "First Monday of October 2012" will not work on PHP prior to version 5.2.7. So if you'r getting any date returned containing the year 1970 - you'll want to omit the "of" in the strtotime() function. However using "First" in strtotime will not work correctly on PHP versions prior to 5.2.7 - but strtotime can still be used for other options like "Last".

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is the point of this?

```
$ahora =strtotime(date("d-m-Y"));
```

You build a string-based date, then turn it back into a time value (which is an integer) with strtotime(). What a waste of CPU cycles. How about

```
$ahora = time();
```

instead?

Comment: Note that `time()` is not exactly equivalent to `strtotime(date("d-m-Y"))`; the latter returns the timestamp for the beginning of the current day, while the former returns the timestamp for the current second. The extra precision will cause different results for the `$ahora <= $fin_invierno` test.